# IIS Configuration - MVC 6 Azure AD Authentication

Tags: azure, iis, server

A little bit about my setup.
I have created an MVC6 project that is using Azure AD authentication.
This is a template I used for my json configuration:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "TenantId": "blahblahblahblahblah",
    "ClientId": "blahblahblahblahblah",
    "ClientCertificates": [
      {
        "SourceType": "StoreWithThumbprint",
        "CertificateStorePath": "CurrentUser/My",
        "CertificateThumbprint": "blahblahblahblahblah"
      }
    ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "blahblahblahblahblah"
  }
}
```

I can run the application from Visual Studios without any problem, but as soon as I try to host it in IIS, I am getting some problems with Azure authentication.

This is what I have tried:

1. I have changed clientid and tenant id and CertificateThumbprint according to my IIS server certificate. I am using Self Signed certificate.
2. I changed http to https otherwise Azure won't redirect my page.
3. What I don't know, if I have to select SSL Required, or should I accept Client

These are errors I am getting (depending if I select "Require SSL" or Ignore client certificate).

- My page on start-up is looping and getting this:
  We couldn’t sign you in. Please try again.
- Bad Request - Request Too Long
  HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.

I am 100% sure if I wouldn't use Azure AD it would display my page without any problem because I have tested it already. Why from Visual Studios I have no problem to run it, but I am getting so many problems in IIS?

Any advise?

Comment: Does it work if change to visual studio certificate?

Answer (score 0):

I used this sample
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph/README.md
And use the Path instead. No error appears in IIS enviroment. [Using certificates](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Using-certificates#specifying-certificates-from-a-certificate-store-by-distinguished-name-by-configuration)

```
    "ClientCertificates": [
      {
        "SourceType": "Path",
        "CertificateDiskPath": "E:\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\SelfSigned1.pfx",
        "CertificatePassword": "123"
      }
    ],
```

It doesn't matter what certificate IIS is using. As long as you keep the appsettings pfx file is exported from the cert you upload to Azure. It works.

Comment: Hello Qiang, 
Thank you for your Answer, but I tried your way and it still keeps loading Microsoft 365 and doesn't authenticate.

Comment: @XtaXCraft Does the official sample have same problem?

Comment: I think I found the problem. Azure requires proper certificate and you must have a proper domain name not just IP.